Decomposing forecast errors into shape and scale components
I'm working on a time series forecasting problem where I predict hourly demand values for each day (24 hours in total). I measure the error of my predictions at the day-level using the Mean Absolute Error (MAE) aggregated across the 24 hours.
I believe that the day-level error can be decomposed into two non-overlapping components:

Shape error: This error occurs when the sum of the predicted 24 hourly values equals the sum of the actual values, but the distribution across the hours is incorrect. In other words, the model captures the total demand correctly but misallocates it across different hours.
Scale error: This error happens when the predicted values follow the correct temporal pattern (the peaks and troughs occur at the right times), but the magnitudes are uniformly scaled up or down by a fixed percentage (e.g., all predictions are consistently 10% higher than the actual values).


Are there any established approaches in time series analysis that address this type of error decomposition?

Any guidance, references, or suggestions on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.
Edit to add:
I am aware of metrics like Spearman Rank correlation and DTW to measure shape error; and metrics like MAPE to measure scale error.
I am looking for a reference or theory that systematically addresses this type of decomposition. At this point, it is just something that I thought up by myself and I would feel better reading up on a more thorough treatment of such decomposition

I hope you are aware of the problems with the MAPE.

I'm thinking of two elements :

Dynamic time warping for the "shape error" (which has the nice effect of not being too sensitive to a shift in time for instance) ;
MAPE (mean absolute percentage error) should do the job for the "scale error".


Thanks for getting back to me. I am aware of these metrics. I am, however, looking for a reference or theory that systematically addresses this type of decomposition. At this point, it is just something that I thought up by myself and I would feel better reading up on a more thorough treatment of such decomposition.

Oh, sorry for the misunderstanding. This paper: https://thome.isir.upmc.fr/papers/DILATE_neurips19.pdf published in NeurIPS may give you hints, even if it is more oriented towards deep learning

Thanks for this fantastic reference. This led me to a more recent paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.15050. In Fig.2 “Amplitude Shifting” and “Phase Shifting” is exactly what I was looking for.

I hope you are aware of the problems with the MAPE.
